# Ошибка с токеном бота телеграм библиотеки aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, token

Выдает вот такую вот ошибку при запуске, токен буква в букву, цифра в цифру, но не работает[image]

> aiogram.utils.exceptions.ValidationError: Token is invalid! It must be
> 'str' type instead of <class 'NoneType'> type.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import os

TOKEN = "token"
bot = Bot(token=os.getenv(TOKEN), parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    start_buttons = ['Старт']
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*start_buttons)

    await message.answer('Search?', reply_markup=keyboard)

def main():
    executor.start_polling(dp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Вы меняете содержимое переменной `token` на реальное значение?  У вас же токен берётся из переменной окружения, если вы стараетесь прочитать переменную по имени, которое равно значению токена `os.getenv("your_token_value")`, то скорей всего получите `None`.

Comment: @NowhereMan Внутри `token` у меня вставлено то, что выдали, а именно допустим 60992074128:AAE1aFydiqwdaIjlRQvU5qycclrLfQhOanes. Немного не понимаю Вас, у меня в ошибке просят, чтобы тип данных был строка, хотя по идее это она и есть. Если внутри `token=os.getenv(TOKEN)` вместо `TOKEN` вставить то длинное значение, то ошибка остается